# Replace multiple columns in a dataframe with a new column that indicates if the original columns contained any non-missing data

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, na

I have a dataframe that resembles the simplified one below. I am hoping to replace columns A:C with a new column (new_column) that provides a 1 for a row with data and an NA for a row without data.

```
A  B  C
NA NA NA
1  0  0
0  1  0
0  0  1
```

The outcome would look something like this:

```
new_column
NA
1
1
1
```

I tried using the mutate command in dplyr

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(new_column = apply(is.na(df[, c("A","B","C")]), 1, all),
         .keep = "unused",
         .before = "D" ) # where D is the next column in the data frame
```

Comment: What if A, B, C are all zeros?

Comment: @DarrenTsai For this dataframe I am considering a 0 data because most of the columns are dichotomous 1 or 0 with NA indicating no data. So if A:C are 0 I would want the new column to say 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below code

```r
library(tidyverse)

data %>% mutate(new=ifelse(!is.na(rowSums(across(c(A:C)))),1,NA))


   A  B  C new
1 NA NA NA  NA
2  1  0  0   1
3  0  1  0   1
4  0  0  1   1
5  0  0  0   1
```

base r approach

```r
data$new_column <- ifelse(rowSums(is.na(data)) == ncol(data), NA, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if_all()` + `is.na`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(new_column = ifelse(if_all(A:C, is.na), NA, 1),
         .keep = "unused")

#   new_column
# 1         NA
# 2          1
# 3          1
# 4          1
```

---

###### Data

```r
df <- structure(list(A = c(NA, 1, 0, 0), B = c(NA, 0, 1, 0), C = c(NA, 
0, 0, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: I am sure I am doing something wrong but I am getting an error code when using this. both when using your example and when using my own data. The error is: Error in `mutate()`:
Caused by error in `if_else()`:
! `false` must be a logical vector, not a double vector.

Comment: @dev `if_else` is type-sensitive in the older `dplyr` version. I use the latest version so I don't have this error. You can explicitly specify the type: `if_else(if_all(A:C, is.na), NA_real_, 1)`, or replace `if_else` with `base`'s `ifelse()`.

Comment: ＠dev Please check my edit! I replace `dplyr::if_else` with `base::ifelse`.